# How to prevent from checking any Item in BottomNavigationMenu

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I use a `BottomNavigationView` .First menu item always comes checked, but in my app, none of menu items must checked at start. How can i do it?

Here is my code:

`my_menu.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="@string/help"
    android:checked="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_question"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
<item android:id="@+id/places"
    android:title="@string/places"
    android:checked="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_places"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:checked="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
<item android:id="@+id/add"
    android:title="@string/add"
    android:checked="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
```

`activity_main_layout.xml` file:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bnvBottomMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/my_menu" />
```

`MainActivity.class` file:

```
bnvBottomMenu.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.help:
                    break;
                case R.id.places:
                    break;
                case R.id.search:
                    break;
                case R.id.add:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Edit: checked="false" parameter not worked

Comment: according to my understanding of your question.. you want all menu item uncheck first. am i right?

Comment: yes,you're right.

Comment: use this in first menu ... actually you were mark first item as checked in xml <item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="@string/help"
    android:checked="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_question"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>

Comment: android:checked="true" this attribute checked you first menu item.. make it android:checked="false". you will get your desire result :)]

Comment: i've already tried it but now worked.Thanks your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

**my_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="@string/help"
    android:checked="false"    //you set this attribute true
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_question"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
<item android:id="@+id/places"
    android:title="@string/places"
    android:checked="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_places"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:checked="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
<item android:id="@+id/add"
    android:title="@string/add"
    android:checked="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
    app:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
```

Comment: I've tried it but not worked, first item came selected  again.Thanks for your suggestion.